# open ads in external browser in webview android

Tags: webview

I created app with webview, and i want load all internal links in webview and load external links in android browser. Now problem is I am using html ads and when i click on ads i want open external browser, but its opening in webview. only problem with ads otherwise everything is works fine. So how can i do this?

My code is below:

`class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

```
@Override   
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) { if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.mysite.com")) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}else{

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;}}`
```

Comment: Can you show us what the ads' link look like, and if there is some js like onclick event is doing something?

Comment: I use simple 3d party banner ads with javascript.(document.write).

Answer (score 1):

You code should be:

```
@Override   
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.mysite.com")) {
        return true;
    }else{
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return false;
    }
}
```

All I changed was:

1.) Returning true loads the URL in the webview, **no need for view.loadUrl()**

2.) Return false when you broadcast the ACTION_VIEW intent

Answer (score 1):

I did the some modifications and it is working perfectly for banner ads.
I have made following changes:

- changed if condition.
- I am returning false for 'if' block as documentation says:

> If WebViewClient is provided, return true means the host application
>   handles the url, while return false means the current WebView handles
>   the url

```
@Override   
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
{ 
    if (url.contains("www.mysite.com")) 
    {
       view.loadUrl(url);
       return false;
    }else
    {
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
       startActivity(intent);
       return true;
    }
}
```